# Debug.WriteLine output no showing for all processes in an application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

My application consists of a solution with multiple projects.  The startup project is a 'launcher' program that allows the user to click a range of buttons, with each button starting a new process that hosts one of my other projects.

I write to the output window using Debug.WriteLine throughout all my projects, but I have noticed that only output from my startup project is being shown in the output window.  If I change the startup project to one of my other projects, then only output from that project is being shown.

How do I get VS2019 to display debug output from all projects/processes?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger only show debug output for process only if debugger attached to this process. So, when your runner starts new process, this new process does not have debugger attached and you will not see debug output.

Some workarounds

- use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) - this will show debug output system-wide
- use VS [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) to automatically attach debugger to child processes (for me this works not very good)
- pause your child process with MessageBox or Debugger.Break(); and attach debugger manually.

Comment: Thanks Serg. I installed both DebugView and the VS extension.  The extension is working well for me and also allows debugging of child processes.